# float number is not displaying correctly in my C program

Tags: c

I'm just trying out a BMI (body mass index) calculator in C, but I keep on getting 0 as the final answer. Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int weight, height;
    printf("Enter your weight in kilograms: ");
    scanf("%d", &weight);
    printf("Enter your height in meters: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Your BMI(body's mass index) is %f\n", weight/height*height);

    return 0;
}
```

It displays 0 as the result.

I just need it to display the number with decimals (using `%f` and using `int` for weight and height).

Comment: All your variables are integers, so it does integer arithmetic, not float.

Comment: Try printing `1/2`. That 'll help you fix your problem.

Comment: @Barmar even if i put float instead of int for the weight and height, i keep getting 0

Comment: @AhmadBenos then you need to [edit] your question to show that code as well.

Comment: @AhmadBenos When you changed the types, did you also change to `%f` in `scanf`?

Comment: i just did it now. sorry i did not see that before :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the variables are integers, it's doing integer arithmetic, and returning an integer result. Printing an integer with `%f` causes undefined behavior.

Cast one of the variables to float to get a float result.

```
printf("Your BMI(body's mass index) is %f\n", (float)weight/(height*height));
```

Also, you have the formula wrong, it should be `weight/(height*height)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I updated the answer with the correct formula for BMI.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.
i just used this:

```
int weight;
float height;
printf("Enter your weight in kilograms: ");
scanf("%d", &weight);
printf("Enter your height in meters: ");
scanf("%f", &height);
printf("Your BMI(body's mass index) is %.2f\n", (weight)/(height*height));
```